# Nginx not starting exists with error: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed

Tags: nginx, snapshot, digital-ocean

Recently, I created a Digital Ocean instance and set it up with a basic LEMP stack. I also connected it to a domain with this nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    root /var/www/example.com;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

A few days later I decided to move things over to a new server so I created a snapshot of this container and fired up a new server with the exact same snapshot/image.

The results were not the same though. When I try to reload Nginx I get this:

```
@:~$ sudo systemctl reload nginx
nginx.service is not active, cannot reload.
```

For some reason, Nginx hasn't started and it exits with an error (log from `/var/log/nginx/error.log`):

```
2020/06/01 16:49:24 [emerg] 1325#1325: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2020/06/01 16:49:24 [emerg] 1325#1325: bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2020/06/01 16:49:24 [emerg] 1325#1325: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2020/06/01 16:49:24 [emerg] 1325#1325: bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2020/06/01 16:49:24 [emerg] 1325#1325: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2020/06/01 16:49:24 [emerg] 1325#1325: bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2020/06/01 16:49:24 [emerg] 1325#1325: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2020/06/01 16:49:24 [emerg] 1325#1325: bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2020/06/01 16:49:24 [emerg] 1325#1325: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2020/06/01 16:49:24 [emerg] 1325#1325: bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2020/06/01 16:49:24 [emerg] 1325#1325: still could not bind()
```

I have tried adding `ipv6only=on` to the config but it did not help. I have also tried to re-install Nginx, but it did not help either.

What could be the issue here? If you're missing any log files, just let me know and I'll update the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
```

means that some application allready used this port? check using:

```
ss -ntlp
```

you will see comething like:

```
State      Recv-Q       Send-Q              Local Address:Port             Peer Address:Port
LISTEN     0            128                       0.0.0.0:5355                  0.0.0.0:*          users:(("systemd-resolve",pid=1089,fd=13))
LISTEN     0            128                       0.0.0.0:22                    0.0.0.0:*          users:(("sshd",pid=1039,fd=4))
```

find application and shut it down, apache running?